# Java: Why can't I properly render colours (RGBA) with LibGdx?

Tags: java, android, colors, libgdx

When I change the colours to blue `Gdx.glClearColor(0,0,255,1)` then it works as it should. But when I use `Gdx.glClearColor(51,204,255,1)`the colour remains white. What do I have to change to make it work?

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) {

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(51,204,255,1); // this makes the screen white
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    camera.update();
    game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

    game.batch.begin();
    game.batch.draw(game.hermine, 0, 0, (int)(game.hermine.getWidth() * 0.25), (int)(game.hermine.getHeight() * 0.25));
    game.batch.end();

    if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
        game.setScreen(new GameScreen(game));
        dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function `glClearColor()` works with a range between 0 - 1.

So `glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);` is white an `glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);` is black.

`glClearColor(0, 0, 255, 1);` works because it's the same like `glClearColor(0, 0, 1, 1);`

`glClearColor(51, 204, 255, 1);` does not work because it's the same as `glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);` and this is white.

You must work in a Range from 0 - 1 so to become your expected result you must write: `Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.2f, 0.8f, 1, 1);`